# Остановить прокрутку страницы при открытом меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код. Мне надо добавить функцию (как я понимаю, это через JS делается), которая при открытии меню не дает пользователю прокрутить вниз/вверх страницу, а при закрытии - возвращала бы эту возможность.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {
        $('nav').toggleClass('active');
    })
})
```

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial; }

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  header .logo {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left; }
  header nav {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px; }
    header nav ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex; }
      header nav ul li {
        list-style: none; }
        header nav ul li a {
          height: 70px;
          line-height: 70px;
          padding: 0 30px;
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          font-size: 20px; }
          header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a.active {
            color: black;
            border-bottom: 5px solid greenyellow; }
  header .menu-toggle {
    color: #FF3032;
    float: right;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none; }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0; }
    header .menu-toggle {
      display: block; }
    header nav {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #fff;
      top: 70px;
      left: -110%;
      transition: .5s; }
      header nav ul {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
        header nav ul li a {
          border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
      header nav.active {
        left: 0; } }

.fake {
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://www.setwalls.ru/pic/201504/1024x768/setwalls.ru-76864.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Main</title>

    <!-- Side links -->
  </script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Adding css -->

    <!-- Adding js -->
<!--     <script src="js/menu_script.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="https://www.48hourslogo.com/Public/images/bg/10.png" alt="Logo">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="fake"></div>
<div class="fake"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: на `html,body` вешаете `toggleClass` с `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При открытом меню вешай на `body` `overflow:hidden`, а при закрытии удаляй.

### Готовое решение

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active');
    $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
  })
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header .logo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header nav ul li a:hover,
header nav ul li a.active {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid greenyellow;
}

header .menu-toggle {
  color: #FF3032;
  float: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  header .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  header nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 70px;
    left: -110%;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  header nav ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  header nav ul li a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  header nav.active {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fake {
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://www.setwalls.ru/pic/201504/1024x768/setwalls.ru-76864.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Main</title>

  <!-- Side links -->
  </script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Adding css -->

  <!-- Adding js -->
  <!--     <script src="js/menu_script.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="https://www.48hourslogo.com/Public/images/bg/10.png" alt="Logo">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="fake"></div>
  <div class="fake"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: спс............

Comment: @Antonio112009 пожалуйста)